# Is it good practice to place logic in object's key-pair values? (sonarqube issue)

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

For following object:

```
hash = {
  a: 1,
  b: x || y
}
```

We check our **sonarqube test coverage**, and apparently, sonarqube says that the hash is covered if first key is covered, because it assumes this:

```
hash = {a: 1, b: x || y}
```

We had a bug where `y` was not defined. So my two questions

1. I couldn't confirm that **sonarqube** treats objects as one-liner. For sure, it didn't check the second key line. We got no red or green colour, meaning, no covered or covered info was provided.
2. Is it good practice to place logic in key values? Because things like this can happen, then you have a bug in something that was not tested, because sonarqube didn't complain about it.

Comment: "We had a bug where y was not defined." - This does not say anything about `x`. For full branch coverage in this line, you need only `x` to evaluate to something falsy and something truthy at least once. There are no conditions on `y`. So, are you sure that there were actually any uncovered branches?

Comment: yes, say y it's a constant that is no where defined. Code is broken, as it was

Comment: As already described above, the value of `y` does not influence branch coverage: there is nothing that forbids it to be `const y = undefined`. The branch coverage depends only on `x`. If `x` is truthy, then `hash.b` becomes `x`. If `x` is falsy, then `hash.b` becomes `y` (which can be `undefined`). Whether `y = undefined` is a suitable fallback value might be debatable, but as soon as you have `x` both truthy and falsy in some of the tests, you have covered both branches.

Comment: and what about if `b: y`? also sonarqube tells: since `a:1` it's covered, all the object is covered, and that is not true